# Why this proof of that equation does not have rational roots works

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, roots

In my textbook proof looks like this:

For equation $x^4 - 3x^3 + x + 2$ Let's suppose that $p/q$ is a root

Then following true
$(p/q)^4 -3(p/q)^3 + p/q + 2 = 0$

Multiplying by $q^4$ we have
$p^4 - 3p^3q + pq^3 + 2q^4 = 0$

Proof consists in that left part is not divisible by $q$ when the right is it.
Why this proof by contradiction works?

Comment: Actually, you need to check only $±1,±2$ by Rational Root Theorem..

Comment: 1/2 for example is rational number too

Comment: you are trying to prove the given eq doesn't have roots right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: The fact that $p, q$ are irreducible is missing. Using the same proof for a general polynomial, you can obtain the rational root theorem: details are on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That proof is missing one statement.  "Let's suppose $p/q$ is a rational root with $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ and $q > 1$."  Notice that for every way to write a rational number, we can make its denominator positive by usual arithmetic rules and can make the numerator and denominator relatively prime by reducing to [lowest terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction).

(There is something sneaky in the above.  When we take $q > 1$, the rest of the argument is correct.  However, this omits what to do when $q = 1$.  The argument in the book does **not** resolve whether there are integer roots.  As a very simple example, $x-1 = 0$ has an integer root.  This argument gives $p/q - 1 = 0$, so $p-q=0$.  If we force $q > 1$, then $q$ does not divide $p$.  However, $q = 1$ is a perfectly valid choice, and $1$ *does* divide $p$, so the argument in the book is missing the case $q = 1$.)

Then at the end, $q$ divides each of $3p^3q$, $pq^3$, $2q^4$, and $0$.  (The latter by $q \cdot 0 = 0$.)  But, because they are relatively prime, $q$ does not divide $p$, so $q$ does not divide $p^4$.  Therefore $q$ does not divide $p^4 -3p^3q + pq^3 + 2q^4$.

In detail, $q$ cannot divide $p^4$ because when we reduced $p/q$ to lowest terms, we ensured that the prime factorizations of $p$ and $q$ do not both contain the same prime.  Suppose a prime is in both factorizations.  Then that prime divides the $\gcd(p,q)$, but since $p/q$ is in lowest terms, $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, so is not divisible by any prime.  The prime factorization of $p^4$ only contains copies of the primes in the prime factorization of $p$, so contains none of the primes in the factorization of $q$, so cannot be divisible by $q$.  This last follows from unique factorization into primes -- up to sign and the ordering of the factors every integer has a unique factorization into primes.

This produces a contradiction: if we assume that there is a rational root, $p/q$ (which we are free to assume is already in lowest terms), we find that $q$ divides $p^4 -3p^3q + pq^3 + 2q^4$.  But this contradicts that $p/q$ is in lowest terms because it requires that $q$ divides $p^4$.  Since the assumption that there is a rational root leads to a contradiction, there is no rational root.

Comment: Your argument does not immediately rule out $q=\pm1$ - agree?

Comment: @peterag : I wouldn't call it my argument.  I'm explaining someone else's defective argument.  If it were **my** argument, I would have handled the case that $q$'s prime factorization is empty as a separate case.

Comment: Sorry! my problem is that I clearly can't read - or at least can't read first paragraphs.

Comment: @peterag : Well, maybe...  Following your comment, I did add a paragraph about the missing integer root case.

Comment: @EricTowers I got the point that proof consists of the fact that eq is not divisible by q, but why it should be divisible by q?

Comment: UPD: Because the right part is divisible whereas left part is not

Comment: @Ilya : Yes.  Here's another way to see that.  From the same equation, we can do a little algebra:  $$  p^4 = 3p^3 q - pq^3 - 2q^4  \text{.}  $$  $q$ is a divisor of every term on the right, so it has to be a divisor of the left, $p^4$.  (... which is impossible because $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime).

Answer (score 3):

By Rational Root Theorem, we only need to check $±1,±2$.

Then, we can easily deduce that any rational root doesn't exist.

Your textbook proof is also works.

If $q>1, ~ \gcd (p,q)=1$ and $x=\dfrac p q$ where $p,q \in\mathbb Z$ then

$$3p^3q- pq^3-p^4 =2q^4$$

$$p(3p^2q-q^3-p^3)=2q^4$$

This means $\gcd(p,q)>1$, which gives a contradiction.

---

**Small Supplement:**

- We can always choose $p$ or $q$, such that $p>0$ or $q>0$.  For convenience, we can accept $q>0.$
- If $q=1$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Then

$$p(3p^2-p^3-1)=2$$

This implies $p=±1,p=±2$, which gives again a contradiction.

Comment: Having posted a stupid comment on Eric's answer... Why does "this [immediately] mean $\gcd(p,q)>1$", immediately being the key word? I grant that there are no (non-trivial) solutions to that last equation, but...  Don't I have to check/reason explicitly, for instance, that $p,q =\pm 1$ doesn't work?

Comment: @peter Interestingly, I saw your comment after editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite addressing your question, per se, and you've accepted Eric's answer, but still this might be useful to you... This is the "rational root theorem," in this particular case.

First of all, $x=0$ is not a root. Assume now that $x=p/q$, with $p$ and $q$  relatively prime (cancel out any common factor), non-zero.

You can rewrite your equation as $$p \cdot \text{stuff} = -2 q^4.$$ That means that $p$ divides $2 q^4$. If $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, it means that $p$ must divide $2$. So $$p=\pm 1, \pm 2.$$ Likewise,  rewriting, your equation says $$ p^4 = q\cdot \text {other stuff}.$$
So $q$ must be a factor of $p^4$. But again, if $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, you must have that $q=\pm 1$. So your only possibilities for a rational root $p/q$ are $\pm 2/1, \pm 1/1= \pm 2, \pm 1$. Try out the four choices. If none work, then there is no rational root.